Dynamically Loading and Using XAML Content in WPF with References to Local Types
I have an application that allows users to define .xaml and .xaml.js files and we use a combination of embedded javascript engines, and dynamically loaded xaml in C# to create a fake desktop enviromnent where you can write wpf applications in javascript.
I haven't needed to do this up to this point, but I now need to reference a user control that's defined in our main WPF application from one of the dynamically loaded xaml documents.
using XamlReader, where Lemur.GUI.ResizableWindow is well defined in our main application, loading this for example:
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lemur.GUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="#474354" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5">
    <Grid>
        <local:ResizableWindow/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

I get errors like :
XAML parsing error: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Lemur.GUI}ResizableWindow'.' Line number '9' and line position '4'.

even though I am loading these control from a program that's already instantiated these types and is using them. From my understanding, I would have to load the assemblies that contain these WPF controls and their associated types, however I don't get why they wouldn't already be loaded since, like I said, we are already instantating and using them.
I have tried loading the assemblies manually into my AppDomain to no avail; I cannot seem to reference these types that are defined in the application that's loading the dynamic xaml documents, within the actual loaded documents.
This is my XAML loading code:
 public static UserControl? ParseUserControl(string xaml) {
     var task = Computer.Current.Window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {
         try {
            return XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as UserControl;
         }
         catch (XamlParseException ex) {
             Notifications.Now($"XAML parsing error: {ex.Message}");
         }
         return null;
     });
     task.Wait();
     return task.Result;
 }

How should I go about actually loading these documents reliably?

I think you need to show the XAML the Xaml Reader is trying parse.

@GerrySchmitz the XAML shown with the UserControl is the sample I am trying to parse, or do you mean the ResizableWindow control that's defined in my main app?

You might need to add the assembly property to your xmlns value and use the xmlns:custom attribute... like so... xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SDKSample;assembly=SDKSampleLibrary". According to the docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#a-basic-custom-mapping-example

Right you are; the presentation order threw me off. That said, UC's in XAML (in my case) often seem to need a "compile" before they'll "take"; which doesn't help your case.

Thank you for your replies @quaabaam I'll try that and get back to you
